# Partial call with type conversion to NonNullable with custom NonNullableArrItems type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have something that looks like the following

```
type NonNullableArrItems<T extends readonly unknown[]> = T extends [infer A, ...infer B]
  ? [NonNullable<A>, ...NonNullableArrItems<B>]
  : []

const doAllExist = (arr: readonly unknown[]) =>
  arr.every((dep) => dep !== undefined && dep !== null)

const useCallbackWhenExists = <
  T extends readonly unknown[],
  U extends readonly unknown[],
  Y extends NonNullableArrItems<T>,
  V
>(
  fn: (...args: [...deps: Y, ...params: U]) => V,
  ...requiredDeps: T
): ((...args: U) => V) => {
  return useMemo(() => {
    if (!doAllExist(requiredDeps)) {
      return noop
    }

    return (...args: U) => fn(...(requiredDeps as Y), ...args)
  }, requiredDeps.concat(fn))
}
```

The idea here is that I take an array of dependencies (from a rest param) that may or may not have typings like `string | undefined`

So it would look something like this:

```
useCallbackwhenExists((id: string, fakeArg: IFakeInterface) => /*doStuff*/, /*someId that might be a string or undefined*/)
```

The error I get is:

```
Argument of type '(id: string, fakeArg: IFakeInterface) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(args_0: string, ...args_1: unknown[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'fakeArg' and 'args_1' are incompatible.
```

If I convert my references to `Y` to just `T` everything just works.

I can also get this to work if rather than leveraging rest params for `fn: (...args: [...deps: Y, ...params: U]) => V` I switch it to `fn: (deps: Y, ...args: U) => V`

What is going on that is breaking this? It looks like my `NonNullableArrItems` mostly works but has some sort of broken typing.

Comment: This code is really hard to understand, you may have have overdone it with the typing.

Comment: Not sure that's the case, when the code is a modification of the partialCall in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements

This has one more type than that.